# ANTLR4: How to match extra spaces at the beginning of a line?

Tags: java, regex, antlr4, lexer

I tried to match the extra space at the beginning of the line, but it didn't work. How to modify the lexer rule to match?

TestParser.g4:

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

root
    : choice+ EOF
    ;

choice:
    QUESTION OPTION+;
```

TestLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

@lexer::members {
    private boolean aheadIsNotAnOption(IntStream _input) {
        int nextChar = _input.LA(1);
        return nextChar != 'A' && nextChar != 'B' && nextChar != 'C' && nextChar != 'D';
    }
}

QUESTION:                      {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? DIGIT DOT CONTENT -> pushMode(OPTION_MODE);
OTHER:                         . -> skip;

mode OPTION_MODE;
OPTION:                        OPTION_HEADER DOT CONTENT;
NOT_OPTION_LINE:               NEWLINE SPACE* {aheadIsNotAnOption(_input)}? -> popMode, skip;
OPTION_OTHER:                  OTHER -> skip;

fragment DIGIT:                [0-9]+;
fragment OPTION_HEADER:        [A-D];
fragment CONTENT:              [a-zA-Z0-9 ,.'?/()!]+? {_input.LA(1) == '\n'}?;
fragment DOT:                  '.';
fragment NEWLINE:              '\n';
fragment SPACE:                ' ';
```

Text:

```
1.title
A.aaa
B.bbb
 C.ccc
2.title
A.aaa
```

Java code:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString("1.title\n" +
                "A.aaa\n" +
                "B.bbb\n" +
                " C.ccc\n" +
                "2.title\n" +
                "A.aaa\n");
        Lexer lexer = new TestLexer(charStream);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        ParseTree parseTree = parser.root();

        System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(parser));
    }

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
(root (choice 1.title A.aaa B.bbb) (choice 2.title A.aaa) <EOF>)
```

The idea is that when a non-option line is encountered in `OPTION_MODE`, the mode will pop up, and now when there is an extra space at the beginning of the line, it is not matched as expected.

It seems that the `\n`  before `C.ccc` matches `NOT_OPTION_LINE` causing the mode to pop up? I want `C.ccc` to match as `OPTION`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making it a bit too complex. As I see it, lines either start as a question (`[ \t]* [0-9]+`) or as an option `[ \t]* [A-Z]`. In all other cases, just ignore the line (`. -> skip`). That boils down to the following grammar:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

QuestionStart
 : {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? [ \t]* [0-9]+ '.' -> pushMode(ContentMode)
 ;

OptionStart
 : {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? [ \t]* [A-Z] '.' -> pushMode(ContentMode)
 ;

Ignored
 : . -> skip
 ;

mode ContentMode;

  Content
   : ~[\r\n]+
   ;

  QuestionEnd
   : [\r\n]+ -> skip, popMode
   ;
```

A parser grammar could then look like this:

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

root
 : question+ EOF
 ;

question
 : QuestionStart Content option+
 ;

option
 : OptionStart Content+
 ;
```

And the Java code:

```java
String source = "1.title\n" +
    "A.aaa\n" +
    "B.bbb\n" +
    " C.ccc\n" +
    "  ...ignored ...\n" +
    "2.title\n" +
    "A.aaa\n";

Lexer lexer = new TestLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));

CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
ParseTree parseTree = parser.root();

System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(parser));
```

will then print:

```
(root (question 1. title (option A. aaa) (option B. bbb) (option  C. ccc)) (question 2. title (option A. aaa)) <EOF>)
```

#### EDIT

Given that you already have target specific code in your grammar, you could just trim the spaces from an option like this (untested!):

```
OptionStart
 : {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? [ \t]* [A-Z] '.'
   {setText(getText().trim());}
   -> pushMode(ContentMode)
 ;
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, because the options I want to match do not contain the preceding spaces, and now the options include spaces in front of them, so I need to deal with these extra spaces separately.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve option matching without leading spaces?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but it'd make the grammar more complicated. But your own solution glued the option number, the dot and the contents all in 1 big token. Compared to that, a space before an options isn't that of a big deal, right? But have a look at my EDIT as well.

Comment: The edited solution seems good so I don't need to deal with spaces separately in the listener/visitor, thanks!